# Classical derivative exists a.e. and is $L^1$. Is $f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f\in L^2(0,1)$ which is continuous on $(0,1]$ and whose classical derivative exists almost everywhere and is in $L^1(0,1)$. Does it then follow that $f(0+)$ exists?

(We actually have $f\in W^{1,2}(a,1)$ for every $a\in (0,1)$. Therefore, the classical derivative exists a.e.. The fact that it is $L^1$ comes from another observation.)

Comment: Here might be an answer: So, we know that $f\in W^{1,2}(a,1)$ for every $a$. Hence, the classical derivative of $f$ coincides with the distributional on $(a,1)$ and we have $f(1)-f(x) = \int_x^1f'(t)\,dt$ for each $x\in (a,1)$ (not only a.e. because $f$ is continuous). Since $a$ was arbitrary, this equation holds for each $x\in (0,1)$ and hence $f(x) = f(1)-\int_x^1f'(t)\,dt$, which implies $f(0+) = f(1) - \int_0^1f'(t)\,dt$. Can anyone check this, please? I am not convinced.

Comment: No. Consider $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb R, x \mapsto \sin(x^{\alpha}) $ for $-1<\alpha<0$. Then $f, f’$ are both continuous and in $L^1$.  (Moreover $f$ is in $L^p$ for every $p>0$). But $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} f(\varepsilon)$ doesn’t exist.

Comment: @LinearOperator32 First: how can one see that the integral converges? Second: What is wrong with my "proof" above? I would be happy if you answered.

Comment: @LinearOperator32 For $f(x) = \sin(x^{-1/2})$ I get $|f'(x)| = \tfrac{|\cos(x^{-1/2})|}{2x^{3/2}}$. Substituting $y = x^{-1/2}$ I get for the integral$$\int_{\varepsilon}^1|f'(x)|\,dx = \int_1^{1/\sqrt{\varepsilon}}|\cos(y)|\,dy,$$which definitely does not converge. So, I strongly doubt your claim.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake; thank you for pointing it out. I’m not sure how you deduce for every $x \in (0,1)$ we have $f(1)-f(x)=\int_x^1 f’ dm$. (In other words, $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[1, x]$ for every $0<x<1$). There are examples of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ which are differentiable a.e. and whose derivative is in $L^1$ but cannot be recovered by integration. This doesn’t give a counterexample to the question at hand, but if possible, could you provide more reasoning to that step?

Comment: @LinearOperator32 I added this paragraph in parentheses in my question, where I assume that $f$ is absolutely continuous on every interval $[a,1]$. Hence, you get in particular that $f(1)-f(a) = \int_a^1f'(t)\,dt$. Letting $a\to 0$ gives $f(0+) = f(1) - \int_0^1f'(t)\,dt$. Is that correct?

Comment: If you assume $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,1]$ for every $0<a<1$, then yes that is correct by the dominated convergence theorem. You’ve assumed $f’$ is in $L^1((0,1]))$ (we may assume $f’ \in L^1([0,1])$ since this is just modifying the function on a null set). So, we can take as our dominating function $|f’|$. Apply the DCT to $f’ 1_{[\varepsilon_n, 1]}$ where $(\varepsilon_n)_n$  is any sequence in $(0,1]$ decreasing to $0$.

Comment: @LinearOperator32 Thanks, that makes it completely rigorous.

Comment: No problem; I apologize for that (rather embarrassing) mistake yesterday.